# Отображение Tray на остальных мониторах

Tags: windows, windows-10, system-tray

Мне нужно отображать Tray на всех мониторах (в моем случае трех), но в windows выводится только на основном. Можете подсказать решения данной проблемы? Т.к. в виндовс нет встроенного функционала, я так понимаю нужна сторонняя программа.

### Что я подразумеваю под треем и как это выглядит на разных мониторах:

Основной:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Другие два монитора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Информация о системе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали этот [способ](https://superuser.com/questions/753549) (которые не работает на Win11)?

Comment: Он подразумевает, что мы переместим основную панель с треем на другой монитор. Но мне нужно отображать на всех мониторах панель с треем.